# Quantile-quantile plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Am I right that this code:

```
QuantilePlot[data, NormalDistribution[Mean[data], StandardDeviation[data]]
```

will return QQ plot of the sample quantiles of our data versus theoretical quantiles from a normal distribution with the same mean and variance as our data have?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., thanks. And if I understand that correctly, the sample quantiles (based on our data) will be on vertical axis and the theoretical quantiles from a normal distribution will be on horizontal axes (based on the code above)?

Comment: Yes, you can check that using the first example on the QuantilePlot page which has uniformly distributed data between 0 and 1. The y axis has the same range. See also the "Scope" section which has an example comparing uniformly distributed data with a theoretical distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct: `QuantilePlot` will plot quantiles of the reference distribution (i.e. *theoretical* quantiles) on the horizontal axis; and *empirical* (i.e. sample) quantiles on the vertical axis.

To convince yourself that *Mathematica* respects that common convention, you can find an example buried deep in the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantilePlot.html) for `QuantilePlot` (look under "Scope" in the "Presentation" subsection) in which WRI has labeled the axes accordingly:

[image: labeled quantile plot from MMA documentation]

Comment: The first entry of "Properties & Relations" is also rather illuminating, methinks. Anyway, OP really should've read the docs.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Quite right. And the example following the one you mentioned, involving plotting data against a `UniformDistribution`, really drives the point home as well. I overlooked those two. The doc page for `QuantilePlot` is surprisingly vast: I still managed to learn something, so not all was lost. Anyway, I think I've already thoroughly flogged this dead horse as it is...